# Is 'access to' redundant here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, redundancy

In a [blog](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/sunanda-pushkar-died-of-poisoning-medical-board/1/576840.html), I read the following line:

> In its report, the Board has also asked the Special Investigation Team to investigate whether someone with ***access to*** either "insulin or hypoglycemic agent" was present near the Leela Palace hotel, where Sunanda died, on January 17, 2014.

To my mind, there is no need to put 'access to' here as the sentence looks ok without putting it:

> In its report, the Board has also asked the Special Investigation Team to investigate whether someone with either "insulin or hypoglycemic agent" was present near the Leela Palace hotel, where Sunanda died, on January 17, 2014.

Is 'access to' redundant here? If no, then what does it signify in the sentence?

Comment: No, it's not redundant. There is a difference between having an access to insulin and having a vial or a pen of insulin with you.

Comment: That's why I asked about the significance also.

Answer (score 5):

> I have **access** to insulin: I have an insulin pen on a bookshelf in my apartment.

Thus, I am a person who has **access** to insulin. However, then I go shopping or riding a bicycle, I don't take the insulin pen with me.

From the investigator's standpoint, I might have the insulin pen with me at any time, because I have access to it. It is the investigator's job to be suspicious of everyone.

So if someone is found dead and with an injection mark on his body, and I was nearby when this death occured, the investigator might suspect me of involvement in the crime.

However, the investigation will have to prove that I **actually had** some insulin with me during that time, because "having access" does not equal "having the insulin pen with you at the time of the crime".

Answer (score 3):

*access* is not redundant here.

When you *have* something, you have it.

When you have *an access* to something, you *don't* have it, but you *can* have it whenever you require it.

Let's create a scene:

> A terrorist has a gun and he entered into the hotel.

Here, the terrorist *has* it. You see *a gun* in his hand.

But then...

> A terrorist has an access to a gun

may mean that you *don't* see a gun in his hands. But **if he wants,** he ***can*** have it. So, either he may have gun in his pocket from where he can have *access* to the weapon **or** in the hotel itself, he has hide the gun somewhere. He has **access** to it.

Comment: This may be a dialect issue, but *access* is normally a mass noun, so it would be "A terrorist has access to a gun" not "*an* access to a gun".

Comment: @stangdon I agree

Comment: "When you have something, you have it" - a non-tautological definition (e.g. *currently possess*) would be much more helpful.

Comment: @stangdon I many not agree with that. Because [*...someone's aim was to give children in rural areas **an access to education.***](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-32111959)

Comment: @MaulikV - This may still be a dialect issue, then.  In US English we would say "access to education".  I noticed the author of that piece has a Japanese name (so she may not be a native speaker) and the BBC presumably uses British usage.  All of the dictionaries I looked at say access is a noncount word.

Comment: Still no! Because the two biggest drivers of Syrians migration are lack of access ***to education*** and lack of access ***to work***. I don't say that, [Deputy Secretary of State Antony Blinken said. Blinken, who served as Obama’s national security adviser](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/24/magazine/why-is-it-so-difficult-for-syrian-refugees-to-get-into-the-us.html?_r=0)! @stangdon

Comment: @MaulikV - I don't get your point.  He's using *access* without an article.  That's what I said was correct.  He's an American, like I am.

Comment: wrong link. I closed all windows. Please wait. @stangdon

Comment: *A scarcity of lawyers can become **an access** to justice issue. In South Dakota, ...* from the [University of St Thomas](http://www.stthomas.edu/news/finding-success-small-town/) @stangdon

Comment: @stangdon *Michelle Obama spoke animatedly at the event, and reminded the roomful of students that education is **an access to power.*** - from USA Today. I have many examples...

Answer (score 1):

Of course if the someone died from an overdose of insulin, somebody would have had to have insulin on their person at the scene, However...

The reason for using the phrase **has access to** might be a technical one.

Insulin is a **controlled substance** so anyone one with normal **access to** it would either have to be of a certain rank or status, or a user.  They may be asking if either a **medical person** or a **diabetic** was at the scene of the crime thereby establishing how the medication was available.

As a corollary, usage of **controlled** substances are logged and there may be a record of where it came from.

Comment: A *side* but useful note: In *India*, we can have *access* to **any drug!** You *don't* need to be diabetic if you want to purchase insulin injection. Nor do you need any prescription. One word for that - ***irony!***

Comment: @MaulikV - same here. It's sold freely in Russia